# How to use condition appropriately in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, mutex

My two Threads, Produce and Consume, don't work well. When I run this code, the console printed 'producing' and 'consuming' one by one. Then, it stopped and program is still running>

```java
class BufferMutex {
    private char [] buffer;
    private int count = 0, in = 0, out = 0;
    private ReentrantLock mutex = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition okProduce = mutex.newCondition(); 
    private Condition okConsume = mutex.newCondition(); 

    BufferMutex(int size) {
        buffer = new char[size];
    }

    public void put(char c) {
        mutex.lock();
        try {
            while(count == buffer.length) { 
                okProduce.await();
            }
            System.out.println("Producing " + c + " ...");
            buffer[in] = c;
            in = (in + 1) % buffer.length;
            count++;
            okProduce.signalAll();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

    public char get() {
        mutex.lock();
        char c = buffer[out];
        try {
            while (count == 0) {  
                okConsume.await();
            }
            out = (out + 1) % buffer.length;
            count--;
            System.out.println("Consuming " + c + " ...");
            okConsume.signalAll();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            mutex.unlock();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `while(count == buffer.length)` seems ambiguous. When one element input in the buffer the buffer.length will be 1, and so is the count. So what is the point here? You want to produce one and then put the Producer into waiting state? Because this way every time you add 1 element into the buffer the producer will be blocked, hence it will produce only one element and get blocked until the consumer consume elements and change the buffer's length.

Comment: @Kozmotronik Umm.. I elided the main code that have buffers numba. Buffer Mutex buffer = new Buffer Mutex(7); But, thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the producer signalling the producer and the consumer signalling the consumer. Don't you want to switch those? Shouldn't the producer signal the consumer and vice versa?

Comment: OMG! You are right! I switch those, and it's worked well! How thankful.... 8-]